# evaluation of the integral of a certain logarithm

Tags: integration

I come across the following integral in my work
$$\int_a^\infty \log\left(\frac{x^2-1}{x^2+1}\right)\textrm{d}x,$$
with $a>1$.

Does this integral converge ? what is its value depending on $a$ ?

Comment: I meaned $a>1$, thank for the comment

Comment: You just need the value or you need to know how to derive it? In any case for $a\geq 1$ the value is $-\pi- 2 arccoth(a) + 2 a \times arccoth(a^2) + 2 arctan(a)$.

Comment: This condition actually simplifies everything. Let me edit my answer.

Comment: To Mehdi at least an hint of how to derive it

Comment: You can tag users by putting an "@" before their user name.

Comment: @ Amadeus: Jack D'Aurizio just wrote an excellent derivation!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using
$$
-i\log\left(\frac{x+i}{x-i}\right)=\pi-2\tan^{-1}(x)
$$
we get
$$
\begin{align}
\int_a^\infty\log\left(\frac{x^2-1}{x^2+1}\right)\mathrm{d}x
&=\int_a^\infty\left[\vphantom{\sum}\log(x+1)+\log(x-1)-\log(x+i)-\log(x-i)\right]\mathrm{d}x\\
&{=}+(x+1)\log(x+1)-(x+1)\\
&\hphantom{=}+(x-1)\log(x-1)-(x-1)\\
&\hphantom{=}-(x+i)\log(x+i)+(x+i)\\
&\hphantom{=}-(x-i)\log(x-i)+(x-i)\\
&=\left[\log\left(\frac{x+1}{x-1}\right)+x\log\left(\frac{x^2-1}{x^2+1}\right)-2\tan^{-1}(x)\right]_a^\infty\\
&=\log\left(\frac{a-1}{a+1}\right)+a\log\left(\frac{a^2+1}{a^2-1}\right)+2\tan^{-1}(a)-\pi
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 4):

We have:
$$ I = \int_{\frac{a^2-1}{a^2+1}}^{1}\frac{\log x}{(1-x)^{3/2}(1+x)^{1/2}}\,dx $$
where the integrand function is integrable over $(0,1)$. Moreover:
$$ 0 > I > \int_{0}^{1}\frac{\log x}{(1-x)^{3/2}(1+x)^{1/2}} = -\frac{\pi}{2}-\log 2.$$
Integration by parts gives:
$$ I = x\,\left.\log\frac{x^2-1}{x^2+1}\right|_{a}^{+\infty}-\int_{a}^{+\infty}x\left(\frac{1}{x-1}+\frac{1}{x+1}-\frac{2x}{x^2+1}\right)\,dx,$$
or:
$$ I = -a\log\frac{a^2-1}{a^2+1}-\int_{a}^{+\infty}\frac{4x^2}{x^4-1}\,dx = -a\log\frac{a^2-1}{a^2+1}-4\int_{0}^{1/a}\frac{dx}{1-x^4}$$
so:
$$ I = -a\log\frac{a^2-1}{a^2+1}-2\left(\operatorname{arccot} a+\operatorname{arccoth} a\right),$$
or:
$$\color{red}{ I = -a\log\frac{a^2-1}{a^2+1}+\log\frac{a-1}{a+1}-\pi+2\arctan a}. $$

Comment: How do you arrive to this integrand $I$ ?

Comment: @Amadeus: With the substitution that makes the argument of the logarithm be $x$.

Comment: I'd have never thought of using integration by parts. +1

Comment: @hjhjhj57 As a tip for the future, integration by parts should be your *first* thought when trying to find complicated antiderivatives involving logarithms (or any other special function defined as an integral).

Comment: @DavidH Thanks for the advice!